# Does Visual Studio have a "deeplink" URL scheme registered like Visual Studio Code does ("vscode://...")?

Tags: visual-studio, url-scheme

I can open a file in Visual Studio Code with a link like `vscode://C/Work/myfile.ts` (and even specify line and column numbers at the end if so desired).

Does Visual Studio itself have a similar URL scheme registered?  I tried `visualstudio://C/Work/myfile.ts` (same with `vs://`) but no luck.